# Does ROS have anything similar to a "global variable"?

Tags: ros, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a node that subscribes data from 3 other nodes (2 nodes publish data in 30Hz while 1 node publishes in about 10Hz). The node I created uses a transformation matrix(4x4) from the slower node (10Hz) to transform data from other 2 faster nodes (30Hz) and publishes them. The problem is that I don't need every single transformation matrix (but occasionally) from the data stream of the slower node and I also don't want this one becomes a bottleneck of this entire process by using message filter time_sync. So, I wonder whether ROS has something similar to a global variable that sits in one place and can be read or modified so that the node I created doesn't have to wait until all data from 3 other nodes get subscribed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392553/does-ros-have-anything-similar-to-a-%22global-variable%22?/) by [kidpaul](https://answers.ros.org/users/72845/kidpaul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2021-12-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bergercookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25299/bergercookie/) on 2021-12-10**:
I don't think there's a global variable concept in ROS1 for this purpose.
Could you perhaps limit the publishing rate of the 10Hz node itself since you want to use it at a lower rate anyway? Or you could have a wrapper node around the 10Hz node that implements that rate reduction and/or potentially caches the transform matrix.

**Comment by [kidpaul](https://answers.ros.org/users/72845/kidpaul/) on 2021-12-10**:
Thank you for the verification! The reason why I want to find something like global variable is to avoid the lower rate publishing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You tagged this `rospy` so I'll assume you're asking about python. Yes, python supports global variables within a single OS process. However, you should implement thread-safety if you read/write such a variable from multiple places in your code, typically by using a mutex.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kidpaul](https://answers.ros.org/users/72845/kidpaul/) on 2021-12-10**:
Thank you for your answer! Yeah, it seems like python global variable is the way to do what I want.